# Ensure the `@ServerRequestFilter` method runs before the `@Produces` method of a class in Quarkus

Tags: cdi, quarkus

I have a class that essentially looks like this. I have found that the order of the methods annotated with `@ServerRequestFilter` and `@Produces` is indeterminent. However, the method annotated with `@ServerRequestFilter` MUST run before the method annotated with `@Produces` for things to work.

How do I enforce that?

```
@RequestScoped
public class ApplicationJwtFactory {

    @Inject
    JWTParser jwtParser;

    private JsonWebToken jwt;

    @ServerRequestFilter
    public void parseAuthorizationHeader(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        jwt = jwtParser.parse(context.getHeaderString("Authorization"));
    }

    @Produces
    public JsonWebToken getJwt() {
        return jwt;
    }

}
```

I tried the `@Priority` annotation and the `priority` property of `@ServerRequestFilter` annotation, but none of those made a difference.

Comment: I don't think there is any formal specification requiring an ordering of these methods. So, even if they happened to run consistently one after another, I would not rely on that. I propose the following refactoring: an interface `JwtHolder` with a `getJwt()` method; `ApplicationJwtFactory implements JwtHolder`; and components requiring the JWT inject the `JwtHolder`, not the `JsonWebToken`.

Comment: One more observation is that you are producing the `JsonWebToken` in *dependent* scope. It could be request scoped. Maybe adding `@RequestScoped` to `getJwt()` will get you what you need, because CDI will be injecting a *proxy* to the `JsonWebToken`, not the class itself, and may delay producing it until it is really needed. Maybe :)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, both of your suggestions worked.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Please post your comments above as an answer so that I can accept it and give you credit. For now I posted an answer myself and referred to your comments, and accepted that. I will change to yours once you've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nikos (in the comments) was on the right track. Both of his suggestions worked separately.